# multiple download NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have a program that download a video from a url using NSURLSession, but i'm not able to do multiple download at the same time.
How can i do it?
How can i manage multiple simultaneous download?

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration    defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getVideo = [session downloadTaskWithURL:fileURL
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSURL *location,
                                                                        NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                        NSError *error) {
                                                        // 2
                                                        receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
                                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                            // do stuff with image
                                                             NSLog(@"%s receiveData:%d",__FUNCTION__,[receivedData length]);
                                                        });
                                                    }];
    [getVideo resume];
```

Comment: Why did you post another question? Just update your previous question if you have more details.

Comment: Where is your original question?  Did it get answered?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided above you are not using any of the properties of NSURLSessionConfiguration class that would enable better download performance.

First of all I would look suggest using your own delegate queue. If you do not provide a queue then the session creates a serial operation queue for all delegate and completion handler calls see the "Creating a Session" section of the [NSURLSession Class Reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) for more detail. You can look at the following properties of [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) to help improve performance;

```
qualityOfService
maxConcurrentOperationCount
```

Next I would look at [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost) properties that may help.

```
HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost
HTTPShouldUsePipelining
```

Finally you should review the section "Life Cycle of a URL Session with Custom Delegates". You should confirm whether your using the delegate methods of [`NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSURLSessionTaskDelegate) and [`NSURLSessionDownloadTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate_protocol/) or just the completion handler.

You need to put more time into configuring NSURLSession to support the work you want to do.